# LinkedIn v2 API does not return the same information as v1, for example follower count by day

Tags: linkedin-api

We’re trying to adjust to the v2 API changes for LinkedIn.

We’re having trouble finding the same information with the v2 API that existed with the v1 API

For instance with v1, we queried the following endpoint, to retrieve the total number of organic and paid followers for the last 30 days

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/<companyId>/historical-follow-statistics?format=json&time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=1548460800000
```

With v2, it looks like we should use this endpoint

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:<companyId>&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1548460800000
```

However, when we include the date range, we only get the paid and organic follower gains instead of the total followers for each day. To get the total followers, we appear to need to drop the date range.

We have built an application that allows our clients to visualize their follower counts and was reliant on having the history for 30 days. What can we do going forward? We no longer have a way to know what the value from 30 days ago was adding to. We want to be able to get this information with 1 query.

Similarly, we are also using the following API

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/<companyId>/num-followers?format=json&geos=na
```

Which we have adjusted to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:<companyId>?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember
```

However, we can no longer filter by geography